# Slack Messages Not Sending on Standard Objects - Via Slack Integration with Salesforce

Tags: apex, integration, invocable-method, webhooks, slack

It's been over a year since the original post, and I'm running into a similar error again. I've quote the original posting below here, but wanted to add additional details to hopefully come across a resolution.

Because of the issue noted in the original posting, I followed [this guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scRij.png) to set up a custom Apex class with Incoming Webhooks. This worked great for a long time.  However, we started running into issues where we noticed we were only getting messages some of the time, but not all. It seemed like there were 'black out' dates where the integration would just not work.  I've worked with Slack and Salesforce support directly, and they could not pinpoint the issue. If the flow was creating a record and sending a Slack message, the record would still created, but the message would not come through to the Slack channel.  We did not receive any Flow failed or paused notifications when this would happen.

Additionally, I ensured nothing had changed in our org and all Slack channel ids and names, SF Flows, and SF Apex had remained constant.

Because of the inconsistency, I re-installed the Slack Integration with Salesforce to our org, hoping the managed package may prove more reliable.

- This included installing [this app (Salesforce - the one built by Slack)](https://simplyhome.slack.com/apps/AKGPGUFP1-salesforce?tab=more_info) in our Slack Org
- I know per [this post](https://slack.com/help/articles/227838227-Salesforce-apps-for-Slack) I will need to update to [Salesforce for Slack - by Salesforce](https://slack.com/apps/A03269G3DNE-salesforce-for-slack) - at some point; I'm not there yet.
- In Salesforce, I've installed and configured the Managed Package through the App Exchange - [Salesforce for Slack](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FnD9mUAF&tab=e)

I know with this integration, you should be able to search records via Slack, use a button in a record to Send to Slack, etc.  However, all we are trying to handle at this point in time is sending a message to a specified Slack channel via a Flow.

Some of these messages will send a link to a custom object.
I had to manually activate that custom object, as the automatic activation for it failed.

I've used [these instructions](https://slack.com/help/articles/360044038514-Configure-Salesforce-for-use-with-Slack) for setup.

To test the integration, I've set up 2 basic flows.

- Flow 1: When a custom_object is created, send a message to a specific test channel.
- Flow 2: When a Lead (standard obj.) is created, send a message to the same specific test channel.

The test channel is receiving a message as intended when the custom obj is created.
The test channel ***is not*** receiving a message when the standard lead obj is created.

I've even duplicated the working Flow and swapped the object from custom to Lead to ensure everything was the same except the triggering object type, and it still is not sending a message.

As this is a managed package, I don't believe I'm able to execute anonymous and just test the apex code to compare the difference (in debug log).

I've set up trace logs on what I believe are the acting Apex classes and triggers within this managed package, however, upon reading further postings, I'm under the impression to access logs on Apex, you have to connect CLI to a Scratch org and do something like `sfdx force:apex:log:get --logid {log id here}`.

I'm an Admin, not a developer, so I feel a bit out-of-scope when it comes to next steps.

Has anyone else had a similar experience with the Slack integration in Salesforce? Or is there anyone who can break down what next steps may be?

Thank you!

---

Original Posting Below - Not entirely relevant now, as we're using Flow. However, the same issue is persisting.

> I have a process flow that should send an email and a slack message
> when a lead is created by a certain user.
>
> When the lead is created and the criteria is met, the email is sent as
> expected.  However, Slack does not receive a message.
>
> I have a Slack alert sent when a custom object is created, and this
> works fine. It just seems to be the standard object alerts that aren't
> sending.  Would there be any reason for this? I've set up the alert
> the same as I set up the custom object alert that works and made sure
> the Message Destination ID was correct. Is there a way to see errors
> that arise from process flows?
>
> [image]

Comment: what does the debug log show for the invocable method?

Comment: This is showing a successful flow, so I'm not sure where else to check

Comment: so, since you are using an invocable method to post to Slack, go to execute anonymous and just test the apex code to compare the difference (in debug log) between standard and custom object.  Using [edit] and posting the apex code after you do this is the next step